# Identify video area in flash using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I would like to identify the position of the flash object where the actual video is rendered using javascript. To be clear, for example in youtube, I would like to identify the position of the player where the video is shown (i.e. just above the control bar).Is that even possible? If it is, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Its possible but not easy. Look into the ExternalInterface class and you can write a callback function to get the info you need.

Comment: As The_asMan is suggesting, this will be possible to accomplish if you can add functionality to the SWF playing the video.  Do you have the ability to update the SWF (to include callbacks)?

Comment: I have no access to the swf object. Assume the page is from an external source and I am only supplying a javascript widget which needs the video area position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have access to the SWF, I would say no.

The only thing I can think of is to place a transparent `<canvas>`-tag over the Flash video, then get the pixel data using `getImageData()`, and compare a couple of frames and analyze what changes and assume that's the video. I have no idea if this would even work, just a thought.